# react-native-branch requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed

Tags: react-native, npm, branch.io

I'm developing an app using [react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) and I want to use [branch.io](https://branch.io/) to get some nice deep links.

I'm running the npm command to install the SDK for branch in react native

`npm i react-native-branch@latest --save`

I get the following message

[image]

And I also get a warning

[image]

It seems like the branch package needs a react version higher than 15.4.0. It feels like 16.0.0-alpha.6 should be a higher version than 15.4.0, so why am I getting this message?

I have the following in my package.json

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.43.4",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

The message you see is just a warning and should not cause any hindrance in installing the React Native Branch SDK. It should not cause any issues with Deep linking either. We cannot impose a restriction on usage of React version `16.0.0-alpha` as we want to ensure we support older versions of React Native and React.

We are looking into better warning messaging or maybe removing the Peer Dependency warning for React altogether.

If you still continue facing issues, could you write into `integrations@branch.io` and we will help you debug the issue further.